# Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, servlets

I am building simple spring application in which I want to call controller from AJAX. 
But face some issues while using servlet-api. I have added dependency in POM file as I am using HttpServletRequest and HttpServletResponse.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

If I am not including this jar dependency, then HttpServletRequest cannot be resolved to a type issue occurred. and If I am including in maven dependencies and add those maven dependencies in Deployment assembly then below mentioned error occurred and tomcat not even started

INFO: validateJarFile(D:\workspaceUtilities.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\SpringControllerWebApp\WEB-INF\lib\servlet-api-2.5.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class

and if I remove maven dependencies from deployment assembly then tomcat server is started but with following error:

SEVERE: Servlet [dispatcher] in web application [/SpringControllerWebApp] threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet

Please help me out in this scanario.

```
Controller class:

package com.src;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

import com.java.Employee;



@Controller
@RequestMapping("/employee/add.htm")
public class EmployeeController {
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody Employee add(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

    System.out.println("EmployeeController--Start");

    Employee employee = new Employee();
    String firstName = request.getParameter("firstName");
    String lastName = request.getParameter("lastName");
    String email = request.getParameter("email");
    employee.setEmail(email);
    employee.setFirstName(firstName);
    employee.setLastName(lastName);

    System.out.println("EmployeeController--End");
    return employee;
    }
     }
```

---

```
web.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" id="WebApp_ID"    version="2.4" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
   <display-name>SpringControllerWebApp</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-   class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: You shouldn't be including the servlet 2.5 jar in your war, and you should be building against servlet 3.0 (since that is what your container implements).

Comment: I have changed from 2.5 to 3.0-alpha-1 but still same error.

Comment: FYI, the Java Servlet spec is [now at 4.0](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=369). The Servlet API library is at 4.0.1, see [the Maven artifact](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api/4.0.1). If at all possible, I strongly suggest using these. [Tomcat 9](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/index.html) implements Servlet 4 technology.

Comment: I still want to know how you're packaging this jar into your war, are you certain you have `<scope>provided</scope>`? The idea is the servlet-api.jar comes from your servlet container at run-time, the error message is pointing to a section of the spec that talks about guarantees the class loader must make - and it makes sense that you're trying to violate them if you're including the servlet-api.jar - although I think you can play with modules in JBoss/Wildfly to do it if you really must (but I don't see that you must).

Comment: yes I have added <scope>provided</scope> too but still no luck